# Dynamic client for Api authentication in my ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

I developed my app and release in app store now my client need to provide extra security in my app. When the user using my app request data from server I want to send dynamic client key to ensure that the request came from my app.

Comment: This is typically done with a challenge key from the server which the app hashes with a known key and returns to the server.  The server then validates the response and issues a session 'ticket' to the client.  The client can then send the ticket with each request so that the server knows the request is valid - see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750014/django-only-accept-requests-coming-from-my-applications/22750476#22750476 for more information.  Depending on the framework you are using on your server there may be something available 'off the shelf' to do this

Comment: You send request two times but I need it in a single atempt...

Comment: Thakns for your fast response.

Comment: Well, you can just send a "secret" value - kind of like a password, but one that identifies the app, not the user.  As long as you use SSL and verify the server identity then it will be reasonably immune to interception, but if someone discovers the secret then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: If we can create any key at the time of app running? like create key by our app cretificate?

Comment: Now you telling we can't create any key by our certificate right?

Comment: Well, you can encrypt a message using a key coded into your program.  You can't really use your app certificate, but you can generate another key pair or even use a symmetric key, but if you don't do challenge-response then someone can potentially intercept the traffic and then steal the "secret" because it will be the same every time.  You can try and encrypt something based on time of day, but clocks will be different and this can cause problems.  The challenge-response method is well proven and avoids session replay

Comment: You know any encryption method pls tell me the link..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html