# Django server side app (maybe a micro blog) and android app client - how to communicate

Tags: android, django, client-server

I am trying to write a Django microblogging server and have a 1) web interface and an 2) android app client

For the android app client, how do I communicate with the Django server? Is there a way to pass ask for an entire class data (say the Class Microblog objects or the Class BlogUser objects) themselves from the django powered server and then just print/display those objects in the android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass objects to mobile client using serialization, there is django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/.

I recommend you to communicate with mobile clients using JSON format.

About client side: http://osamashabrez.com/client-server-communication-android-json/

Comment: Thanks much. I checked out, and this indeed is the server side portion of the communication. Would be grateful if you point me towards a doc that shows how an android app can receive (and also send) such JSON data? Is there a tutorial that combines both - the server side and the android app side - communication using JSON format?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: http://osamashabrez.com/client-server-communication-android-json/ It's about client side.

Comment: Hi, I know this is quite old but I wanted to know how do I differentiate a json object coming from my app to json object coming from any where else ?

Comment: @AV198 If I understand you right, you want some kind of authentication. You can find some manuals like this: https://techstricks.com/api-authentication-django-and-android-apps/. If you don't need authorization and just want to protect your back-end from requests outside, you need to sign requests somehow. Maybe this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750014/django-only-accept-requests-coming-from-my-applications.